# Python PyFPDF Change Of Image Causes A Crash

Tags: python

I am using a PHP script to call a Python script using the passthru() command. The Python script outputs a PDF.

I am attempting to change an image in the header section of the PDF. However whatever I change it to the Python script seems to crash when called via passthru. If I call it on the command line it works. However if I switch back to the original image then it also works through passthru.

The working image and the non-working image have the same permissions and owner and sit in the same directory.

Anyone know what might be going wrong here?

Comment: Can’t help, sorry. Why are you using PHP to call a python script? Is it possible to call the script without PHP (using the shell), or with another method?

Comment: The reason is that the user needs to call the generation from a web page. The webserver has PHP enabled and using the original image the python script spit out the PDF and PHP passed it through as a file download.